# Spinner not clearing

Tags: android, spinner, adapter

I have a weird bug which I'm not sure why it's happening,

I have 2 activities: activity A and activity B.

When the app starts, it initializes a spinner once. I go to the second activity and then go back <-

`onRestart()` of the Activity A will be called. My problem is that even though I clear my spinner and reinitialize it in `onRestart()` it keeps reading the values.

For example, if spinner has 1/2 when you go to activity B then back to activity A, spinner has = 1/2/1/2.

I find this weird because when I just set the spinner adapter to null and comment out my initialize of spinner when I go back to activity A from activity B, my spinner is empty.

here is my code:

```
  @Override public void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        Spinner location = findViewById(R.id.spinnerLocation);
        location.setAdapter(null); 


        initSpinner();// if this is commented out spinner is cleared, if not commented the same valus are added again


    }
```

here is code for initSpinner(reads from shared prefs) this is not the problem

```
public void initSpinner(){
        Spinner location = findViewById(R.id.spinnerLocation);
location.setAdapter(null);
        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("Locations", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //preffilename
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
      editor.putString("1","St. Catharines");
      editor.putString("2","Toronto");
      editor.putString("3","Niagara Falls");
        editor.commit();
        int s = prefs.getAll().size();




            for(int f=0;f<25;f++) {
                if (prefs.getString(String.valueOf(f + 1), null) != null) {
                    DefaultLocations.add(prefs.getString(String.valueOf(f + 1), null));


                }
            }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, DefaultLocations);
//set the spinners adapter to the previously created one.
        location.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: Manually clear the spinner before calling init

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do
`DefaultLocations.clear()` before for loop inside `initSpinner()` method it may not clear when u adding new values